# Angular custom select element - remember selected item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got the following code;

```
  <select class="pi-native-dropdown--native-dropdown" data-ng-model="country" data-ng-options="country.countryLegend for country in countries track by country.countryLegend" data-ng-change="setCountry(country);validatePostcode()">
 </select>
  <img class="pi-native-dropdown--flag" data-ng-src="{{country.flagImg}}" alt="">
```

Its a select item with ng-options. When a user makes a selection - the image updates accordingly. This sets the correct image source corresponding to the country which the user has selected.

Upon first load, I am loading a default country. Something which I am already doing using the below;

```
$scope.selectedItem = {"countryCode":"A","countryLegend":"Österreich","passportRequired":true,"dialingCode":"+43","flagImg":"/content/dam/global/flags/Austria.png"};
```

What I am trying to achieve:

I would like the select field to memorise the users selection, so that when the user comes back - the select field will have the remembered choice along with the correct image.

Any ideas?

You can find a codepen here:
http://codepen.io/AntonioVassilev/full/GZdRLq/

Comment: can you show me full countryList array ?

Comment: What do you mean by "when the user comes back"?  Do you mean they can navigate to another page and then come back and you'd like to persist their selection?